# Xcode: AWS SDK which I added with CocoaPods doesn't work?

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

I am trying to start work with AWS SDK on iOS. I did all that they said here [AWS SDK GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) with CocoaPod. My pod file looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

pod 'AWSCore', '~> 2.2'
pod 'AWSSNS', '~> 2.2'

end
```

But then I try to import something from AWS:

```
#import <AWSiOSSDKv2/AWSCore.h>
```

I have an error in Xcode: `'AWSiOSSDKv2/AWSCore.h' file not found`
What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you should import headers based on the Pod name, like this:

```
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had success with just `import AWSCore`